TypeError: blog.map is not a function
I can't figure out why my app can't detect object.
Every time my app's component calls ".map", the error I wrote is shown.
I made sure index.js passed props.
Please elaborate why it happens. And give some advice to fix it.
Thanks in advance.
component/List.js
import React from 'react'
import Link from "next/link";

function List(blog) {
    return (
        <div id="blog-list">
        {blog.map((blog) => (  // Error is triggered on this line
            <div className={styles.div}>
            <ul className={styles.ul}>
                <li className={styles.li} key={blog.id}>
                <Link href={`/blog/${blog.id}`}>{blog.title}</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default List;

Here's index.js.
import Head from "next/head";
import List from '../components/List'
import { client } from '@/libs/client'
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "@/styles/Home.module.css";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home({ blog }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <div id="new-blog">
        <Link href="/blog/create" className="">
            <button className="">ブログを作成</button>
        </Link>
        </div>
        <List blog={blog} />
      </main>
    </>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {

  const data = await client.get({
    endpoint: 'blogs',
  })

  return {
    props: {
      blog: data.contents,
    },
    revalidate: 1
  }
}


The definition of your List component is wrong. Components always receive props as an object.
In your example,
function List(blog) {
    return (

You have named the props object to blog, instead of extracting the blog property passed onto the component.
You can fix this by destructuring the blog property from the component's props like:
function List({ blog }) {
    return (


It works! And thank you so much. Your explanation is easy to understand.
